# Galton Board - circles collapse when stacking

Tags: geometry, matter.js

Is the following behaviour is a feature, a bug or a limitation in matter.js? Looking at the Demo : Galton Board (Round 2) at [LoneKorean - GitHub](https://lonekorean.github.io/javascript-physics/) I noticed that after 30 to 45 seconds in running the demo, the stacked circle merge together and the columns of circles in the separators down below collapse. The demo speed is ok at first, then after 30 seconds or so, it almost stops. Then the collapse happens and the speed goes back to "normal".

Is this how it works? How can I prevent this so the height of each bin makes a normal distribution? If matter.js cannot do this, what other physics engines would be appropriate to use?

I tried to set some parameters like density, friction, friction-air, restitution but I could not find the right combination where the circles keep being stacked in a nice column without collapsing.